# Consuming ws from java

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have a problem that's making me crazy.

I want to consume a web service, so I created a client using Eclipse from its WSDL, but it doesnt work, but when i use another tool like XMLSpy it works.

The soap message sended from my Java code (not working) is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
     xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <JRPM056.Execute>
            <Personas>
                    <ns1:pais xmlns:ns1="Personas">845</ns1:pais>
                    <ns2:tpdoc xmlns:ns2="Personas">1</ns2:tpdoc>
                    <ns3:ndoc xmlns:ns3="Personas">39858460</ns3:ndoc>
                    <ns4:apell1 xmlns:ns4="Personas">Recoba</ns4:apell1>
                    <ns5:apell2 xmlns:ns5="Personas">Viana</ns5:apell2>
                    <ns6:nombre1 xmlns:ns6="Personas">Rodrigo</ns6:nombre1>
                    <ns7:nombre2 xmlns:ns7="Personas">Romualdo</ns7:nombre2>
                    <ns8:fecnac xmlns:ns8="Personas">2011-12-01</ns8:fecnac>
                    <ns9:fecvto xmlns:ns9="Personas">2011-12-31</ns9:fecvto>
                    <ns10:sexo xmlns:ns10="Personas">M</ns10:sexo>
                    <ns11:estciv xmlns:ns11="Personas">2</ns11:estciv>
                    <ns12:domicilio xmlns:ns12="Personas">
                        <ns13:domicilios.domiciliosItem xmlns:ns13="domicilios">
                            <ns13:tdomi>4</ns13:tdomi>
                            <ns13:dpto>10</ns13:dpto>
                            <ns13:local>10</ns13:local>
                            <ns13:calle>Convenc</ns13:calle>
                            <ns13:puerta>1465</ns13:puerta>
                            <ns13:aparta>301</ns13:aparta>
                        </ns13:domicilios.domiciliosItem>
                        <ns14:domicilios.domiciliosItem xmlns:ns14="domicilios">
                                <ns14:tdomi>3</ns14:tdomi>
                                <ns14:dpto>10</ns14:dpto>
                                <ns14:local>10</ns14:local>
                                <ns14:calle>Araucho</ns14:calle>
                                <ns14:puerta>1359</ns14:puerta>
                                <ns14:aparta>1</ns14:aparta>
                        </ns14:domicilios.domiciliosItem>
                    </ns12:domicilio>
                    <ns15:telefono xmlns:ns15="Personas">
                            <ns16:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem xmlns:ns16="sdttelefonos">
                                <ns16:tdomici>2</ns16:tdomici>
                                <ns16:telefono>27073963</ns16:telefono>
                                <ns16:sitdomi></ns16:sitdomi>
                            </ns16:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem>
                            <ns17:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem xmlns:ns17="sdttelefonos">
                                <ns17:tdomici>1</ns17:tdomici>
                                <ns17:telefono>099514254</ns17:telefono>
                                <ns17:sitdomi></ns17:sitdomi>
                            </ns17:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem>
                            <ns18:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem xmlns:ns18="sdttelefonos">
                                <ns18:tdomici>0</ns18:tdomici>
                                <ns18:telefono>099514254</ns18:telefono>
                                <ns18:sitdomi></ns18:sitdomi>
                            </ns18:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem>
                        </ns15:telefono>
                <ns19:Ocucod xmlns:ns19="Personas">1</ns19:Ocucod>
                <ns20:Actcod xmlns:ns20="Personas">1</ns20:Actcod>
                <ns21:empresa xmlns:ns21="Personas">MI</ns21:empresa>
                <ns22:fecing xmlns:ns22="Personas">2011-12-01</ns22:fecing>
            </Personas>
            </JRPM056.Execute>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Error Message:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<WS.ExecuteResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/action/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Name of parameter 2 different than expected.</faultstring>
        <detail>2</detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</WS.ExecuteResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The soap message sended from XML spy (working) is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
     xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
     xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <JRPM056.Execute>
            <Personas>
                    <ns1:pais xmlns:ns1="Personas">845</ns1:pais>
                    <ns2:tpdoc xmlns:ns2="Personas">1</ns2:tpdoc>
                    <ns3:ndoc xmlns:ns3="Personas">39858460</ns3:ndoc>
                    <ns4:apell1 xmlns:ns4="Personas">Recoba</ns4:apell1>
                    <ns5:apell2 xmlns:ns5="Personas">Viana</ns5:apell2>
                    <ns6:nombre1 xmlns:ns6="Personas">Rodrigo</ns6:nombre1>
                    <ns7:nombre2 xmlns:ns7="Personas">Romualdo</ns7:nombre2>
                    <ns8:fecnac xmlns:ns8="Personas">2011-12-01</ns8:fecnac>
                    <ns9:fecvto xmlns:ns9="Personas">2011-12-31</ns9:fecvto>
                    <ns10:sexo xmlns:ns10="Personas">M</ns10:sexo>
                    <ns11:estciv xmlns:ns11="Personas">2</ns11:estciv>
                    <ns12:domicilio xmlns:ns12="Personas">
                        <ns13:domicilios.domiciliosItem xmlns:ns13="domicilios">
                            <ns13:tdomi>4</ns13:tdomi>
                            <ns13:dpto>10</ns13:dpto>
                            <ns13:local>10</ns13:local>
                            <ns13:calle>Convenc</ns13:calle>
                            <ns13:puerta>1465</ns13:puerta>
                            <ns13:aparta>301</ns13:aparta>
                        </ns13:domicilios.domiciliosItem>
                        <ns14:domicilios.domiciliosItem xmlns:ns14="domicilios">
                                <ns14:tdomi>3</ns14:tdomi>
                                <ns14:dpto>10</ns14:dpto>
                                <ns14:local>10</ns14:local>
                                <ns14:calle>Araucho</ns14:calle>
                                <ns14:puerta>1359</ns14:puerta>
                                <ns14:aparta>1</ns14:aparta>
                        </ns14:domicilios.domiciliosItem>
                    </ns12:domicilio>
                    <ns15:telefono xmlns:ns15="Personas">
                            <ns16:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem xmlns:ns16="sdttelefonos">
                                <ns16:tdomici>2</ns16:tdomici>
                                <ns16:telefono>27073963</ns16:telefono>
                                <ns16:sitdomi></ns16:sitdomi>
                            </ns16:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem>
                            <ns17:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem xmlns:ns17="sdttelefonos">
                                <ns17:tdomici>1</ns17:tdomici>
                                <ns17:telefono>099514254</ns17:telefono>
                                <ns17:sitdomi></ns17:sitdomi>
                            </ns17:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem>
                            <ns18:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem xmlns:ns18="sdttelefonos">
                                <ns18:tdomici>0</ns18:tdomici>
                                <ns18:telefono>099514254</ns18:telefono>
                                <ns18:sitdomi></ns18:sitdomi>
                            </ns18:Sdttelefonos.SdttelefonosItem>
                        </ns15:telefono>
                <ns19:Ocucod xmlns:ns19="Personas">1</ns19:Ocucod>
                <ns20:Actcod xmlns:ns20="Personas">1</ns20:Actcod>
                <ns21:empresa xmlns:ns21="Personas">MI</ns21:empresa>
                <ns22:fecing xmlns:ns22="Personas">2011-12-01</ns22:fecing>
            </Personas>
            </JRPM056.Execute>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I´m trying to figure out the diference, to get any clue about why is not working from my generated by eclipse client.
Thanks !

Comment: Include the code where you actually consume the WS.

Answer (score 0):

your schema does not make any sense.  namespace "tns3" is not defined anywhere, and your various type names do not match at all.  is this the actual schema?  if so, i'd try making it correct first.

Comment: I´ve added the two soap messages, the one sended bye xmlSpy, that works perfect, and the one generated from my java code (the client is being generated with eclipse). thanks.

Comment: Yeah, namespaces should be used wisely. But in these horrible times, some evil software allows such madness hehehe. Anyhow, if the WS allows the second message...

Comment: @Alfabravo - i was actually commenting on the schema included in the original version of the question, which was most likely invalid.

Comment: @jtahlborn it was invalid beacuse i put a little fragment of the wsdl.Now i put the soap messages, because i think that can be easy for you to help me with this info. Do you have any idea why one of the soap messages is accepted and the other one dont? do you find some important diferences? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Rodrigo - the only difference between those 2 xml docs is an extra schema (SOAP-ENC) in the first doc.